# Autocomplete for css selectors in class attribute of html elements not working with phpstorm

Tags: css, intellij-idea, autocomplete, phpstorm

i have a php file with this in header:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/material.min.css" type="text/css">
```

rightclicking / F3 clicking the file, takes me to the css file, so they are connected.

now when i start using a css class I know exists in the class attribute of a div element, i get no autocompletion.

e.g.

```
<div class="mdl-cell--8-"></div>
```

this does not work in a php file nor blade file nor html file.

is there a way to enable it?

Comment: do you have `<style>` section in your html/php? Completion from external stylesheets doesn't work if there is an embedded style

Comment: @lena i tried it out in several test files, none of them included a style tag

Comment: please create a support ticket then